# Subscription from java client to python opcua server doesn't work

Tags: python, publish-subscribe, opc-ua

I'm trying to get a Java client to subscribe to a few tags on a OPCUA Server I made with Python OPCUA. I can connect to the server fine, even browsing the tree and just reading values isn't a problem, I just can't get the subscription to work like it does with a KepserverEX.

The client can subscribe to tags on a Kepserver, so I don't think the client logic is the problem. It's got to have something to do with the way I programmed the server.

This is the code I used for the server:

```
class SubHandler(object):

"""
Subscription Handler. To receive events from server for a subscription
"""

def datachange_notification(self, node, val, data):
    print("Python: New data change event", node, val)

def event_notification(self, event):
    print("Python: New event", event)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARN)
    logger = logging.getLogger("opcua.address_space")
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # setup our server
    server = Server()
    server.set_endpoint("opc.tcp://0.0.0.0:4840/freeopcua/server/")
    server.set_server_name("Python Docker OPCUA Server")

    # setup our own namespace, not really necessary but should as spec
    uri = "2"
    idx = server.register_namespace(uri)

    # create a new node type we can instantiate in our address space
    dev = server.nodes.base_object_type.add_object_type(0, "MyDevice")
    sb1 = server.nodes.objects.add_object(idx, "Machine")

    my_dict = {}
    tag_data = json.load(open("tag.json"))
    for tag in tag_data['tags']:
        my_dict[tag] = sb1.add_variable(idx, tag, 0)
        my_dict[tag].set_writable()

    server.start()
    print("Available loggers are: ",        logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict.keys())
    try:
        while True:
            handler = SubHandler()
    finally:
        server.stop()
```

The error I'm getting is that the NodeIds I'm trying to subscribe to are unknown. However, when I'm trying to just read the values from the server, the NodeIds are known and I can retrieve values. So that's not the problem either.

I don't know what I'm missing here, do I have to implement some kind of pub/sub logic myself or does the base server already have that?

Comment: "I just can't get the subscription to work like it does with a KepserverEX" what does it mean? You get error when you try to subscribe to give node, or you don't get updates? If the latter -- I don't know Python stack, but in C# you need to notify the server the new value is good (or not), update the node time etc.

Comment: It means that my java code for subscribing to nodes works with the KepserverEX, but it doesn't with a python opcua server. I'm getting an error when I try to subscribe to a node, which is that the NodeId I'm trying to subscribe to is unknown.